# How to upload video in ionic for ios platform?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to upload video in ios using ionic and angular js but I am unable to do so. If any one help me to do so it will be great

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], read [ask] and show a [mcve] of what you have done so far to handle this issue.

Comment: I have selected a file from ios device using $cordovaCamera.getPicture() plugin. I got the local file path of the video file where it is located in device.

Comment: Now i have to convert that .MOV file to base64 string but i am unable to convert it to base64 string no plugin is available for converting the video file which is selected to base64. Also the $cordovaCamera returns only local file path of the video file.

Comment: If you have any solution then please share with me it will be a good help